# Where to locate virtual environment installed using poetry | Where to find poetry installed virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-poetry

I installed poetry using the following command:-
`(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -` 
To know more about it refer [this](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation).

Now I wanted to create a virtual environment, that I created it using the following command:-
`poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`
To know more about it refer [this](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project).

But after doing this, I can`t see any .venv(virtual environment) folder.

To check if virtual environment is there, we use the following command:-
`poetry config virtualenvs.in-project`
and if the above command return `true`, implies you have it.

I'm getting `true`, also the location mentioned on the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project) I cant see it there.

Could anyone tell me how to locate the virtual environment now?

Comment: You need to run `poetry install` once, so that the venv is created. Have you done this?

Comment: @finswimmer, Yup I tried that too.
Though nothing happened.

Later on using `poetry env info -p`, i got to know its on the wrong location somehow, I`m not sure why.

While creating the VE, I was in the right directory.
Still, I found it somewhere else.

Everything is fine now.

I rasied this question bcz I was not able to locate it as well as it was not at the location mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are 2 commands that can find where the virtual environment is located.

1. `poetry show -v`
   The first line of this command will tell you where the virtual environment is located.
   And the rest will tell you which packages are installed in it.
2. `poetry env info -p`
   The above command will give you just the location of the virtual environment.

Comment: this not working for me

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Error was that I was not currently in the venv. I had to start the shell first, then the path for THAT shell showed.

Comment: and if you want to find out the size of each of your poetry venvs:

`du -sh $(dirname $(poetry env info -p))`

Comment: Zaffer - That's weird.  Both of the above commands (as well as `poetry debug info`) produce the same output for me whether or not I'm currently in the Poetry shell.